# Многопоточность в С#

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Есть класс Bank. Нужно построить класс так чтобы при изменении одного из его свойств создавался поток, который запишет данные о свойствах в текстовый файл. Класс должен инкапсулировать в себе всю логику многопоточности. Помогите дальше сделать.

```
class Bank
{
    private int money;
    private string name;
    private int percent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler Changed;

    public int Money
    {
        get { return money; }
        set
        {
            money = value;
            Update();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Update();
        }
    }

    public int Percent
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set
        {
            percent = value;
            Update();
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual void Update([CallerMemberName] string names = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = Changed;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(names));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: А при чем здесь `PropertyChangedEventHandler`? Что именно не получается?

Comment: @aepot думал сделать событие на Update(), запись в файл

Comment: Вы в курсе, что I/O операции не требуют создания потоков и могут просто выполняться асинхронно? Зачем вам здесь потоки? Если это учебное задание "сделать с потоками", ты как минимум должны начать его решать. А пока я вижу попытку реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` без самого интерфейса, что в принципе бессмысленно и не будет работать с UI приложения. Что значит `который запишет данные о свойствах в текстовый файл`? Логирование изменений?

Comment: @aepot это учебное, так понял: свойство name - его значение нужно записать

Comment: Понятие "записать" слишком абстрактное. Строка `Свойство Name было изменено, новое значение "Банк 2"` - это считается, что записали? Или вам нужно обновлять в файле значения свойств класса, то есть сериализовать класс в файл и при изменении любого свойства обновлять в файле данные? Что значит "записать"?

Comment: @aepot да, сериализовать  и каждый раз обновлять

Comment: Ок, серализовать во что? JSON, XML, двоичные данные, свой какой-то формат?

Comment: @aepot в json удобнее всего будет

Comment: Окей, с этим разобрались, теперь вот это `Класс должен инкапсулировать в себе всю логику многопоточности.` Что значит? Все свойства класса должны быть потокобезопасные, то есть должно быть допустимо изменить любое свойство из любого потока? Или же изменение свойств будет из одного потока, а имеется ввиду, что запись на диск просто будет работать в другом потоке?

Comment: @aepot изменения происходят в одном потоке, при изменение создается новый поток с записью

Comment: Что из этого вам знакомо: Producer/Consumer, IDisposable, Reader/Writer Lock? Если вы ждете, что я сейчас сяду и напишу за вас домашнее задание, то зря. Я всего-лишь вам помогаю привести ваш пустой вопрос в порядок. Кстати, внесите в вопрос все, что я выпытал у вас в комментариях. И конкретизируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на конкретной задаче, типа вот у вас есть тех.задание, вот вы его пытаетесь реализовать, и что именно на каком этапе у вас не получается (например: "не могу создать поток, как это сделать?"). Это всё нужно, чтобы повысить шансы получить конкретный ответ.

Comment: @aepot ага, IDisposable и Reader/Writer Lock знаю что это, спасибо хоть за какую то помощь, сам не совсем понимаю, то что в задание написано то и делаю

Comment: Значит у вас есть контекст, раз задание такое абстрактное - записи лекций, методички, учебники, что-то еще, то есть то, чего у меня нет. Я могу выполнить эту задачу тысячей способов. С сотней разных поведений. Так как мне из вашего вопроса непонятно практически ничего. Отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы хоть кому-то стало что-то понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно правильно реализовать `PropertyChanged`, то не надо выдумывать велосипедов, а просто использовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```cs
public class Bank : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int money;
    private string name;
    private int percent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Money
    {
        get { return money; }
        set
        {
            money = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Percent
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set
        {
            percent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Но ваше задание вообще не про это.

Как вы указали, вам требуется реализовать сохранение данных класса в файл с использованием стороннего потока каждый раз, когда данные поменялись. На помощь приходит шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer, `BlockingCollection` и `ReaderWriterLock`.

Насмотря на на принцип SRP из SOLID, который говорит нам, что класс должен делать что-то одно, я реализовал вам пример монстра, который может всё, `PropertyChanged` тоже оставил. По хорошему, класс с данными должен выглядеть как тот, что я выше показал, а все остальные должны быть реализованы в других внешних классах.

```cs
public class Bank : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping };
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> queue;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLock locker;
    private readonly string fileName;
    private Thread writerThread;

    private int money;
    private string name;
    private int percent;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Bank(string fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        locker = new ReaderWriterLock();
        writerThread = new Thread(WriterLoop);
        writerThread.IsBackground = true;
        writerThread.Start();
    }

    public int Money
    {
        get 
        {
            locker.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            try
            {
                return money;
            }
            finally
            {
                locker.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            CheckDisposed();
            locker.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            money = value;
            locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get 
        {
            locker.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            try
            {
                return name;
            }
            finally
            {
                locker.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            CheckDisposed();
            locker.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            name = value;
            locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Percent
    {
        get
        {
            locker.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            try
            {
                return percent;
            }
            finally
            {
                locker.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
        set
        {
            CheckDisposed();
            locker.AcquireWriterLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
            percent = value;
            locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void WriterLoop()
    {
        foreach(string json in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            File.WriteAllText(fileName, json);
        }
    }

    private void SaveData()
    {
        locker.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        try
        {
            queue.Add(JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, options));
        }
        finally
        {
            locker.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        SaveData();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(nameof(Bank));
    }

    bool disposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            CheckDisposed();
        if (!disposed)
        {
            queue.CompleteAdding();
            PropertyChanged = null;
            writerThread.Join();
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~Bank() => Dispose(false);
}
```

Почему `IDisposable`, потому что поток надо остановить, когда мы перестаем классом пользоваться, иначе он будет выполняться до тех пор, пока приложение не будет закрыто. Можно было и обычный метод `public void Stop()`, но тогда бы в случае, если вы забыли задиспозить класс, он бы продолжал при изменениях свойств писать в файл.

Потестируем и запись и INPC

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string fileName = "bank.json";
    using (Bank bank = new Bank(fileName))
    {
        bank.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Value '{e.PropertyName}' was changed to '{typeof(Bank).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(bank)}'");
        bank.Name = "Bank 1";
        bank.Percent = 5;
        bank.Money = 100;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Value 'Name' was changed to 'Bank 1'
Value 'Percent' was changed to '5'
Value 'Money' was changed to '100'
{
  "Money": 100,
  "Name": "Bank 1",
  "Percent": 5
}
```

В итоге решение выглядит весьма монструозно и меня здесь могут побить за нарушение SOLID, но я предлагаю лишее из класса вам выкинуть самостоятельно, например `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Кстати, по поводу использования файла, ошибку конфликта доступа к файлу легко воспроизвести: просто закомментируйте строчку `writerThread.Join();`, и приложение упадет с исключением, говорящим что невозможно прочитать файл, который уже используется. А все потому что оно в этом случае не будет ждать завершения потока, записывающего в файл.

Comment: сколько писанины, спасибо конечно за помощь, многое стало понятно но это же учебное задание и мне кажется можно было сделать проще

Comment: @Yoda так сделайте :) Я пишу код не для преподавателя, а для вас, чтобы вы учились. А для преподавателя вы сами напишите.

Comment: да, сейчас буду с этим всем что то думать)

Answer (score 0):

Консоль:

```
 class Bank
{
    private int money;
    private string name;
    private int percent;

    delegate void UpRead();
    event UpRead update;

    public Bank(string name, int money, int percent)
    {
        this.money = money;
        this.name = name;
        this.percent = percent;
        update += Threading;
    }

    public int Money
    {
        get { return money; }
        set
        {
            money = value;
            update();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            update();
        }
    }

    public int Percent
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set
        {
            percent = value;
            update();
        }
    }

    protected void Threading()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Save));
        thread.Start();
    }

    protected void Save()
    {
        string s = name + " " + money.ToString() + " " + Percent.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText("date.txt", s);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved to file date.txt");
    }
}
```